# Jersey 1 to 2 Migration, using org.codehaus.jettison packages (MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json)

Tags: json, jersey, jettison

Updating an OSGi/Spring web application to Jersey 2.  Currently things are compiling and installing fine with Jersey 2, but I get this error when our resources are accessed:

> *MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject, genericType=class
>   org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.*

Current configuration details for org.codehaus.jettison.json as ‘media provider’ for jersey.

•   Added dependency on jersey-media-json-jettison

•   I’m specifying the org.codehaus package here in web.xml with glassfish specific init-param:

```
<init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>
                    org.codehaus.jettison.json,
                    ...
      </param-value>
</init-param>
```

•   Added package to our webapp bundles bnd file:

```
org.codehaus.jettison.json,\
```

Which shows it’s successfully importing it in the OSGi console:

```
Imported packages  

org.codehaus.jettison.json; version="1.3.3"
```

Console also shows the package being used by the jersey-media-json-jettison bundle:

```
packages org.codehaus.jettison.json  
 org.codehaus.jettison.json; version="1.3.3"<org.codehaus.jettison.jettison_1.3.3 [121]>  
    org.glassfish.jersey.media.jersey-media-json-jettison_2.22.1 [192]
```

Any ideas what's missing here to configure json provider?

Does using `org.codehaus.jettison` packages require programmatic configuration to work as json provider?

Am I asking the right questions?

thank you,
Tom

Comment: Am I asking *a* right question?

Comment: Am I asking a question?

Answer (score 0):

Jettison has a `MessageBodyWriter` and `MessageBodyReader`for `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject`s. For some reason, it does not get auto discovered, even with jettison version > 2.9 (at least for me, this was the case). Maybe because it is not annotated with `@Provider`.
What solved this issue for me was to manually add the respective class to my ResourceConfig:

```
register(JettisonObjectProvider.App.class);
```

After this, creating responses like

```
Response.ok(new JSONObject(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

worked just like with jersey 1.